# How to Split 52 card Into 26 card in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a card game in JavaScript involving 2 players. I'm looking for a way to split the 52 cards in 2 decks of 26 cards each for each player to use. But all I could achieve so far spreading the 52 cards all over the entire page.

My code so far:

```js
var cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs"];
var deck = new Array();

function getDeck() {
  var deck = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {
      var card = {
        Value: cards[x],
        Suit: suits[i]
      };
      deck.push(card);
    }
  }
  return deck;
}

function shuffle() {
  // for 1000 turns
  // switch the values of two random cards
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
    var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
    var tmp = deck[location1];

    deck[location1] = deck[location2];
    deck[location2] = tmp;
  }

  renderDeck();
}

function renderDeck() {
  document.getElementById('deck').innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var value = document.createElement("div");
    var suit = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    value.className = "value";
    suit.className = "suit " + deck[i].Suit;

    value.innerHTML = deck[i].Value;
    card.appendChild(value);
    card.appendChild(suit);

    document.getElementById("deck").appendChild(card);
  }
}

function load() {
  deck = getDeck();
  shuffle();
  renderDeck();
}

window.onload = load;

function split() {
  const list = cards()
  const half = Math.ceil(list.length / 2);
  const firstHalf = list.slice(0, half)
  const secondHalf = list.slice(-half)
}
```

```css
.deck {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: solid 10px black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #808080;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin: 3px;
}

.btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .value {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card .suit {
  background-image: url('card.png');
  height: 100px;
  width: 90px;
}

.card .diamonds {
  background-position-y: 100px;
}

.card .hearts {
  background-position-x: 90px;
}

.card .clubs {
  background-position-x: 90px;
  background-position-y: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="deck">
  <h1>A Deck of Cards</h1>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</a>
  <div id="deck"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Split 52 card Into 26 card in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555985/how-to-split-52-card-into-26-card-in-javascript)

Comment: @MarkusMeyer That duplicate link is this question.

Comment: it's a duplicate. It's different Url. I guess you posted twice.  /questions/72555986/ <> /questions/72555985/

Comment: no its not duplicate could u please help me

Comment: Should it be marked duplicate as a way of getting an answer? One of them should be deleted.

Comment: @Aravind your `split` function does some weird actions. this: `const list = cards()` is simply wrong... cards it's an array and not a function. Plus you are supposed to split the deck not the cards array

Comment: @DiegoDeVita could u please help me with the code .,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives each card in turn to 2 players :

```js
const cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
const suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs"]
let player1 = player2 = []
const deckOrigin = cards.reduce((res, card) => [...res, ...suits.map(suit => ({Value: card, Suit: suit}))], [])
let deck = [...deckOrigin]
const deckplayer1 = document.getElementById('player1')
const deckplayer2 = document.getElementById('player2')
const shuffle = () => {
  deck = [...deckOrigin]
  countCards()
  player1 = player2 = []
  let currentIndex = deck.length,  randomIndex
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex)
    currentIndex--
    [deck[currentIndex], deck[randomIndex]] = [deck[randomIndex], deck[currentIndex]]
  }
  deckplayer1.innerHTML = ''
  deckplayer2.innerHTML = ''
}

const countCards = () => {
  document.getElementById('countCard').innerHTML = deck.length
}

const renderDeck = (div, ele) => {
    let card = document.createElement("div")
    let value = document.createElement("div")
    let suit = document.createElement("div")
    card.className = "card"
    value.className = "value"
    suit.className = "suit " + ele.Suit

    value.innerHTML = ele.Value
    card.appendChild(value)
    card.appendChild(suit)

    div.appendChild(card)
}
countCards()
const split = () => {
  if (deck.length%2) {
    renderDeck(deckplayer2, deck.pop())
  } else {
    renderDeck(deckplayer1, deck.pop())
  }
  countCards()
}
```

```css
.deck
{
    width:50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background:dodgerblue;
    border:solid 10px black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}

.player {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.card
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    margin: 3px;
}

.btn
{
    background:white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius:30px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.card .value{
    font-size:15pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.player-name {
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.card .suit
{
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}

.card .diamonds
{
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}

.card .hearts
{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}

.card .clubs
{
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
   

</head>

<body>
    <div class="deck">
        <h1>A Deck of Cards</h1>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="split()">split</a>
        <div id="countCard"></div>
        <div class="player-name">Player1</div>
        <div class="player-name">Player2</div>
        <div class="player">
          <div id="player1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
          <div id="player2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try it :

```js
const cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
const suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs"]
let player1 = player2 = []
let deck = cards.reduce((res, card) => [...res, ...suits.map(suit => ({Value: card, Suit: suit}))], [])
const deckEle = document.getElementById('deck')
const deckplayer1 = document.getElementById('player1')
const deckplayer2 = document.getElementById('player2')
const shuffle = () => {
  let currentIndex = deck.length,  randomIndex
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex)
    currentIndex--
    [deck[currentIndex], deck[randomIndex]] = [deck[randomIndex], deck[currentIndex]]
  }
  deckplayer1.innerHTML = ''
  deckplayer2.innerHTML = ''
  renderDeck(deckEle, deck)
}

const renderDeck = (div, arr) => {
    div.innerHTML = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        let card = document.createElement("div")
        let value = document.createElement("div")
        let suit = document.createElement("div")
        card.className = "card"
        value.className = "value"
        suit.className = "suit " + arr[i].Suit

        value.innerHTML = arr[i].Value
        card.appendChild(value)
        card.appendChild(suit)

        div.appendChild(card)
    }
}
renderDeck(deckEle, deck)
const split = () => {  
  deckEle.innerHTML = ''
  player1 = deck.slice(0, deck.length/2)
  renderDeck(deckplayer1, player1)
  player2 = deck.slice(-deck.length/2)
  renderDeck(deckplayer2, player2)
}
```

```css
.deck
{
    width:50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background:dodgerblue;
    border:solid 10px black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}

.player {
  width : 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.card
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    margin: 3px;
}

.btn
{
    background:white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius:30px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.card .value{
    font-size:15pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card .suit
{
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}

.card .diamonds
{
    background-position-y: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.card .hearts
{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-position-x: 90px;
}

.card .clubs
{
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
   

</head>

<body>
    <div class="deck">
        <h1>A Deck of Cards</h1>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="split()">split</a>
        <div id="deck"></div>
        <div class="player">
          <p>Player1</p>
          <div id="player1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
          <p>Player2</p>
          <div id="player2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code working on here but not working on local machine

Comment: What framework do you use to code?

Comment: Hi its worked thanks and appreciated.,, Also Could you please guide me for how to pick a random card and display separately in a new windows or a new deck., Kindly help me with the code.,

Comment: Can you talk more description about it?

Comment: Sure I right now 52 cards can shuffle and split., i need like a button called Pick a card., if we click the button a random 1 card from 52 cards should display on a new window or new deck as like ., split function.,,

Comment: Wait for me about 2 o'clock, I'm going to have dinner. It's 8 o'clock

Comment: sure okay.,,,,,,,

Comment: Do you want to deal each card in turn to 2 players!? or show each card in turn after the shuffle!?

Comment: yes each card turn for 2 players

Comment: Waiting for your response.,

Comment: I added it 2 days ago at the top of the answer .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code, but for the specific problem you are asking, this line is the problem:

```
const list = cards()
```

Your `cards` variable is not a callable function, it's an array. You cannot call it by `cards()`.

You want this:

```
const list = cards
```

But `cards` is not a list of 52 cards, but a list from Ace to K. Your deck is `deck`,  so you really just want:

```
const list = deck
```

```js
var cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs"];
var deck = new Array();

function getDeck()
{
    var deck = new Array();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++)
        {
            var card = {Value: cards[x], Suit: suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

function shuffle()
{
    // for 1000 turns
    // switch the values of two random cards
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var tmp = deck[location1];

        deck[location1] = deck[location2];
        deck[location2] = tmp;
    }

    renderDeck();
}

function renderDeck()
{
    document.getElementById('deck').innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
    {
        var card = document.createElement("div");
        var value = document.createElement("div");
        var suit = document.createElement("div");
        card.className = "card";
        value.className = "value";
        suit.className = "suit " + deck[i].Suit;

        value.innerHTML = deck[i].Value;
        card.appendChild(value);
        card.appendChild(suit);

        document.getElementById("deck").appendChild(card);
    }
}

function load()
{
    deck = getDeck();
    shuffle();
    renderDeck();
}

window.onload = load;
function split()
{
const list = deck;
const half = Math.ceil(list.length / 2);    
const firstHalf = list.slice(0, half)
const secondHalf = list.slice(-half)

console.log(list.length);
console.log(firstHalf.length);
console.log(secondHalf.length);
}
```

```css
.deck
{
    width:50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background:dodgerblue;
    border:solid 10px black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}

.card
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    margin: 3px;
}

.btn
{
    background:white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius:30px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.card .value{
    font-size:15pt;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card .suit
{
    background-image: url('card.png');
    height: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}

.card .diamonds
{
    background-position-y: 100px;
}

.card .hearts
{
    background-position-x: 90px;
}

.card .clubs
{
    background-position-x:90px;
    background-position-y:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
   

</head>

<body>
    <div class="deck">
        <h1>A Deck of Cards</h1>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" onclick="split()">Split</a>
        <div id="deck"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but the i need to split the 52 card into 2 column or row for 2 players

Comment: need to display in html page

Comment: right now the result is displaying in console i need to display it on Html page

Comment: You figured out how to display `deck` in `renderDeck`, you can figure this out too.

Comment: Hai i tried but i unable to do that., I'm new for js., could u please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question.